# Avoiding Header Key changing to lower case in Go while posting

Tags: go, http-headers

Unable to make a post request as Go keeps changing the header case to lower /Upper

I am trying to make a post to an URL and I need to ensure that the headers case matches. Example I have a header called HealthCheck, but when I make the post the server receives the key as Healthcheck, where the C is now in lowercase.
I tried

```
req.Header.Set("HealthCheck", "Test")
```

and

```
req.Header.Add("HealthCheck", "Test")
```

and

```
req.Header["HealthCheck"] = []string{"Test"}
```

and the error the server send is 'missing header HealthCheck'. The header received on the servers side is Healthcheck and they need this to be in the Case as they specified which is HealthCheck.
I know that GO is changing the header to it canonical form, but is there a way to avoid it. The server where I am posting this to has millions of users and they are not going to make any changes on their end. I have to come up with a solution for this.
Also I can make the request easily in Python and the headers stay as I want them to be.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `req.Header["HealthCheck"] = []string{"Test"}` to force the header name to `HealthCheck`.   Run [this program](https://go.dev/play/p/bzzdNDtGVlm) to observe the headers written to the network.

Comment: The server in question is not HTTP-compliant: [HTTP header names are case-insensitive](https://httpwg.org/specs/rfc9110.html#fields.names).